# Plot exporting to PDF with incorrect font on macOS

Tags: export, plot-themes

I have a plot that uses the font `TeX Gyre Pagella`. Which is not a native font of Mac OS but I installed it through the font book to all users and the system.

In the output itself of Mathematica it looks completely fine (it didn't before I installed the font for obvious reasons). But when I click `save to pdf` the font changes to another one (don't know which).

Why is this happening? Why would the exportation of the plot change the font it uses? I have been exporting to `.png` and use the plot like that but I lose quality and the vectorized plots which I prefer.

Thanks!

---

Edit:

I am using Mathematica 11 and macOS Mojave 10.14.4

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: Mathematica 11. The same I was using in Linux where the same `.nb` was working fine but that's because the font is native to it (I think),

Comment: Your issue resembles this question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183053/pdf-export-on-macos-mojave-produces-bold-fonts

Comment: Yes! Very similar! It gets fixed by exporting via the `print` command they mention in their answers. Thanks!

Comment: In that case, I'll mark this as a duplicate, since you found a solution on that question. (It seems the _real_ solution is to upgrade to 12 )

Comment: Yes. I wasn't even sure it was out but will update as soon as I can

Comment: Mathematica 12 doesnt have this problem in MacOS Mojave.